# VERY intermittent "Self-assigned IP" on Mac M1

Tags: network, thunderbolt, ethernet

My connectivity looks like this ->

M1 -> (thunderbolt) -> Belkin Hub -> (ethernet) -> Ubiquity Switch -> (ethernet) -> Ubiquity UDM -> (ethernet) -> Cable modem

I have a really weird intermitment connectivity thing, where the wired connection will only get a real IP *some* of the time. Not zero and not 100% of the time.

Wifi works well, as well as a Windows PC that I connect to the same thunderbolt hub.

I *THINK* it's some kind of ordering with the network interfaces - but I have the ethernet at the top. I've tried disabling/deleting my VPNs and no benefit there either.

I've deleted NetworkInterfaces.plist, and rebooted several times. Anyone seen anything like this?

[image: Network Interfaces Control Panel]

Comment: When you say ‘ordering with the network interfaces’, are you looking at the Set Service Order list from the ellipsis button available from the bottom of the sidebar? Just double-checking!

Comment: yeah, i was under the impression that they prioritize according to the order - my mistake if not!

Comment: They are prioritised by an order, but it’s a different one to the list on the left. From the options ellipsis button at the bottom of the list and choose Set Service Order, see if Ethernet is at the top of that list too.

Comment: unfortunately, no joy. The USB is first. I've deleted all the other adapters but the MSFT and Wifi ones.

Comment: FWIW, it's now (randomly overnight) connecting ... is there anything I can do to capture its current state to replicate it in the future?

Comment: I have a similar issue with a MBP16 (M1 Pro).
Tried with 4 different external Ethernet adapters. AFAIK it has started after upgrading the MacOS from 12.0.1 to 12.1.